# write column names to csv file in python if they dont already exist

Tags: python, csv

My problem is that I need to create a csv file with video information that will write the column names to the first row then append rows of information for each video that is uploaded. As you can see below, it will open the blank csv file `videos.csv` and then check the first row for if the column names exist already, if they don't it will write them in, if they do it will continue and append the video information underneath. However at the moment when I run this, the csv file is blank yet it does not write the column names in, it will only write the video information in.

```
    #check for column names
    with open('videos.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] in reader is not None:
                continue
            else:
                with open('videos.csv', 'w') as file:
                    writer = csv.writer(file)
                    writer.writerow(["id", "fileName", "videoName", "description", "genre"])
    
    #append video information
    with open('videos.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        randomId = str(random.randint(1,1000000))
        fileName = os.path.basename(filePath)
        writer.writerow([randomId, fileName, videoName, description, genre])
```

Comment: Read here [Reading/Writng files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files). I think you are looking for `r+`.

Answer (score 1):

A quick example

```
import csv
import random 

with open('videos.csv', 'r+') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    if reader.line_num == 0:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(["id", "fileName", "videoName", "description", "genre"])
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    randomId = str(random.randint(1,1000000))
    writer.writerow([randomId, 'test', 'videoName', 'description', 'genre'])

cat videos.csv 
id,fileName,videoName,description,genre
996548,test,videoName,description,genre
```